# How do I create price rules in Magento based on a particular product type?

Tags: magento

I need to make "catalog price rules" or "Shopping Cart price rules" based on product type (simple, grouped, configurable...)

Is that possible ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am also interessted by this option ( using SCP: simple configurable product), so CART pricerules should be applied only to SIMPLE product, not CONFIGURABLE ones